# JVM Memory Allocation

Tags: java

Hi I Have a question about inheritance. In Java, a subclass object have inside it an object of its superclass?

When JVM allocate space for subclass object, allocates space for superclass field/method? Thanks.

Example:

```
class Bar {
    public String field;

    public Bar() {
        this.field = "Bar";
    }
}

class Foo extends Bar {
    public String field;

    public Foo() {
        this.field = "Foo";
    }

    public void printFields() {
        System.out.println("Base: " + super.field);
        System.out.println("This: " + this.field);
    }
}
```

In execution, will print "Bar" and "Foo". Where Java allocate space to mantain both value for "field"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Java will allocate space for two object references--one for `Foo.field` and the other for `Bar.field`. Loosely speaking, this can be a way to visualize an instance of `Foo` in memory:

```
[header] (references Foo.class, Bar.class, Object.class, among other details)
[Section for Bar]:
    Field, declared type String, referencing a `java.lang.String` with value "Bar"
[Section for Foo]:
    Field, declared type String, referencing a `java.lang.String` with value "Foo"
```

The offsets of these fields are known to the JVM and are used when reading/writing them.

Note that this does not imply `Foo` contains a `Bar`, but rather `Foo` is a `Bar` and more.

Comment: @JCoder That information isn't shown, but it's something I wrote to illustrate the concept.

Answer (score 1):

> In Java, a subclass object have inside it an object of its superclass.

No. A subclass does not "contain" its parent object. Inheritance is an "is-a" relationship. An instance of `Foo` is an instance of `Bar`. Not that `Foo` contains `Bar`.

> When JVM allocate space for subclass object, allocates space for superclass field/method?

Yes. Although the subclass `Foo` has a field with the same name (hence "shadowing" the parent's field), there are still two fields allocated in memory.

Comment: Thanks :) Same for you. I try to give you a "+" vote but I can't

Comment: private fields and methods on the superclass are inherited, they're just not accessible. The memory is allocated whether the child class can access them or not.

Comment: @codelark You're right! Thanks. Strictly speaking though, `private` fields are allocated but not _inherited_.